# Excel VBA Help - PDF Export Run-Time Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pdf

I have macro which generates PDFs from data I insert into a sheet. The amount of PDF I need to generate differs from week to week. I have button I click and it runs the following code. It copies the data from the active tab to a template sheet and then exports that template as a PDF.

```
Sub makePDFS()

Sheets("Do Not Touch").Visible = True

    Dim activeTab As Worksheet
    Dim templateTab As Worksheet
    Dim fieldsTab As Worksheet
    Dim invoicestab As Worksheet
    Dim fullFilePath As String
    
    Set activeTab = Worksheets("Do Not Touch")
    Set templateTab = Worksheets("Template")
    Set fieldsTab = Worksheets("Fields")
    Set invoicestab = Worksheets("Bulk Invoices")
    
    Dim targetRangeToReplace As String
    targetRangeToReplace = "A3:H29"
    
    Dim colFileName As Integer
    colFileName = 34
    
    Dim colFilePath As Integer
    colFilePath = 35
    
    Dim replaceRange As Range
    Set replaceRange = activeTab.Range(targetRangeToReplace)
    
    Dim templateRange As Range
    Set templateRange = templateTab.Range(targetRangeToReplace)
    
    For r = 5 To invoicestab.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        templateRange.Copy replaceRange
        For Each field In fieldsTab.Range(fieldsTab.Cells(2, 1), fieldsTab.Cells(fieldsTab.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
            'field.Value
            'field.Offset(0, 1).Value
        
            For Each cell In replaceRange
                cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, field.Value, invoicestab.Cells(r, field.Offset(0, 1).Value).Value)
            Next cell
        Next field
        'save to pdf
        fullFilePath = "J:\Invoices\" & invoicestab.Cells(r, colFileName).Value
        
            activeTab.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
        fullFilePath, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
        invoicestab.Cells(r, colFilePath).Value = fullFilePath
       
    Next r

Sheets("Do Not Touch").Visible = False

End Sub
```

The issue I have is that once all of the PDFs have been generated as it goes through the loop, it will invariably come to a blank row. When it tries to generate a PDF for this blank row, I get the following error message: run-time error '-2147024773 (8007007b)': Document not saved.

I suspect, because the row is empty, that there isn't a valid filepath but I cant for the life of me figure out how to stop the loop once it reaches a blank row.

Anyone know how?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! "I suspect, because the row is empty, that there isn't a valid filepath but I cant for the life of me figure out how to stop the loop once it reaches a blank row." Test whether the cell/row is not empty. If it is not, generate the pdf file. If it is empty, you do nothing.

Comment: Have a look at `Do Until` to iterate until you hit a blank row

Comment: Caveat for the `Do Until` which works great if you want to totally stop the VBA when you hit the blank row. However, if there are more rows below that need to be process, then you'll have to put in some type of `if then` to determine whether to perform the pdf processing or skip to the next r(ow)